# SceneKit - render surface normal of a geometry

Tags: xcode, scenekit, scnnode, scngeometry

In Xcode SceneKit editor, its possible to visualise surface normals of a SCNGeoemtry

[image]

It seems that the editor uses SCNGeometrySource.Semantic to render the image:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource/semantic

How can I render the surface normals of a geometry to an image?

Comment: I have probably a solution how to render this on screen. But I have actually no idea how you could generate the UV map as an image (similar the Bake-Function in Blender), if this is your goal? Let me know.

Comment: need to just  render (same as the normals on the screenshot) to an image

Comment: I'll prepare something for you

Comment: @ZAY, thanks! looking forward! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give it a try. You can achieve a normal or normal like shading of your geometry by using a `SCNProgram()` for rendering. This replaces the entire rendering which is provided by Apple (like `constant`, `phong`, `blinn`, or `physicallyBased`)

Start using for example with the default SceneKit Template that comes along with Xcode, the one that contains the rotating spaceship.

First, create a Metal-File, and call it `shaders.metal`.

**Variation 1 (first Image below):**
Copy the following code into this file.
*(this code here will generate a **World Space** Normal Map)*

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

// Nodebuffer
struct MyNodeBuffer {
    // float4x4 modelTransform;
    // float4x4 inverseModelTransform;
    float4x4 modelViewTransform; // required
    // float4x4 inverseModelViewTransform;
    float4x4 normalTransform; // required
    // float4x4 modelViewProjectionTransform;
    // float4x4 inverseModelViewProjectionTransform;
};

// as is from StackOverflow
typedef struct {
    float3 position  [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)  ]];
    float3 normal    [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticNormal)    ]];
    float4 color     [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticColor)     ]];
    float2 texCoords [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0) ]];
} MyVertexInput;

// MARK: - Structs filled by Vertex Shader
struct SimpleVertexNormal
{
    float4 position [[ position ]];
    float3 normal;
};

// MARK: - Normal Shader
vertex SimpleVertexNormal myVertexNormal(MyVertexInput in [[stage_in]],
                                   constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                                   constant MyNodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]])
{
    float4 modelSpacePosition(in.position, 1.0f);
    float4 eyeSpacePosition(scn_node.modelViewTransform * modelSpacePosition);
    
    SimpleVertexNormal out;
    
    out.position                    = scn_frame.projectionTransform * eyeSpacePosition;
    out.normal                      = in.normal;
    
    return out;
}

fragment float4 myFragmentNormal(SimpleVertexNormal in [[stage_in]])

{
    // Normal Color
    float3 normal           = normalize(in.normal);
    float3 normalColor      = float3(abs(normal));
    
    // Final Color
    float4 color            = float4(normalColor, 1.0);
    return color;
}
```

**Variation 2 (second image below):**
Copy the following code into this file.
*(this code here will generate a **Tangent Space** Normal Map)*

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

// Nodebuffer
struct MyNodeBuffer {
    float4x4 modelViewTransform;
    float4x4 normalTransform;
};

// Vertex Input
typedef struct {
    float3 position  [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition)  ]];
    float3 normal    [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticNormal)    ]];
    float4 color     [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticColor)     ]];
    float2 texCoords [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0) ]];
} MyVertexInput;

// Vertex Output
struct SimpleVertexNormal {
    float4 position [[ position ]];
    float3 normal;
    float3 tangent;
    float3 bitangent;
};

// Vertex Shader TANGENT SPACE NORMAL MAP
vertex SimpleVertexNormal myVertexNormal(MyVertexInput in [[stage_in]],
                                        constant SCNSceneBuffer& scn_frame [[buffer(0)]],
                                        constant MyNodeBuffer& scn_node [[buffer(1)]])
{
    SimpleVertexNormal out;

    // Transform position to eye space
    float4 modelSpacePosition = float4(in.position, 1.0);
    float4 eyeSpacePosition = scn_node.modelViewTransform * modelSpacePosition;

    // Transform normal to world space
    float3 worldSpaceNormal = normalize((scn_node.normalTransform * float4(in.normal, 0.0)).xyz);

    // Use arbitrary vectors to generate the tangent and bitangent
    float3 arbitraryVector1 = float3(1, 0, 0);

    // Calculate tangent
    out.tangent = normalize(arbitraryVector1 - dot(arbitraryVector1, worldSpaceNormal) * worldSpaceNormal);

    // Calculate bitangent
    out.bitangent = cross(worldSpaceNormal, out.tangent);

    // Ensure that tangent and bitangent are orthogonal to the normal
    out.bitangent = normalize(out.bitangent - dot(out.bitangent, worldSpaceNormal) * worldSpaceNormal);
    out.tangent = cross(worldSpaceNormal, out.bitangent);

    // Transform normal, tangent, and bitangent to world space
    out.normal = normalize((scn_node.normalTransform * float4(in.normal, 0.0)).xyz);
    out.tangent = normalize((scn_node.normalTransform * float4(out.tangent, 0.0)).xyz);
    out.bitangent = normalize((scn_node.normalTransform * float4(out.bitangent, 0.0)).xyz);

    // Transform position to clip space
    out.position = scn_frame.projectionTransform * eyeSpacePosition;

    return out;
}

// Fragment Shader
fragment float4 myFragmentNormal(SimpleVertexNormal in [[stage_in]])
{
    float3 normalColor = 0.5 * (in.normal + 1.0); // Convert to [0, 1] range
    return float4(normalColor, 1.0);
}
```

In the the GameViewController insert the following function, that will attach this shader to a given Node (you can also define the SCNProgram globally and re-use it).

```
func applyNormalShader(node: SCNNode) {
    let sceneProgramNormal = SCNProgram()      // Metal Shader Program
    sceneProgramNormal.fragmentFunctionName    = "myFragmentNormal"
    sceneProgramNormal.vertexFunctionName      = "myVertexNormal"
    
    node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.program = sceneProgramNormal
}
```

the last step is filing a Node to that shader. I'll use the default Spaceship here. *(Make sure to file the exact node containing the geometry you want to shade with that custom shader program.)*

Modify Code like this:
(here: in `viewDidLoad`)

```
// retrieve the ship node
let ship = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!

// animate the 3d object
ship.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 2, z: 0, duration: 1)))

// apply shader
applyNormalShader(node: ship.childNodes.first!)
```

[image: World Space Normal Mapping]

[image: Tangent Space Normal Mapping]

*Hope this will help in some way.*

Comment: massive thanks for helping @ZAY! but are you sure the normal map is correct? its very different from the SceneKit example. I think it's maybe safer to eget it from the render pass (and then convert to normals)?     renderPassDescriptor.depthAttachment.texture = depthTexture

Comment: I think, what the shader produces could be a so called "World space normal map" and what you would like to have is a "Tangent Space normal map". (also check this: https://www.artstation.com/blogs/typhen/GZdL/this-is-normal-3-types-of-normal-maps). For the moment I cannot tell you how to modify the shader to get the normal map you are looking for. If I find a solution, I'll post it here.

Comment: wow, thanks so much man! that worked perfectly! one thing is... did you note that the color is lighter then the original SceneKit normals (and other game engines)? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I've seen both within normal maps (lighter and more saturated purple styles.) Try to change the fragment shader code like so: float3 normalColor = 0.5 * (in.normal + 0.25); you can actually play with that numbers to find your perfect colorisation.

Comment: brilliant, thanks so much again!

Comment: @Zay - have you ever used [[attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTangent)]]; when youre setting up vertex inputs?

Comment: no, I actually have no experience with that